# Quantum states and state vectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors

Does a state vector correspond to only one quantum states and the components in the state vector correspond to different states of this quantum state or is it that the components of the state vector correspond to different quantum states?

Also is it correct to say that (presuming that only one quantum state is discribed by a state vector) a particle can move between the states described by the components of the state vector easily but not between quantum states?

Comment: In quantum mechanics, I believe *state vector* is short for *quantum state vector,* so your question boils down to the difference between *quantum state* and *quantum state vector.*

Comment: Consider some more independent research on the topic of quantum states. This is not a bad place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quantum state and the state vector is exactly the same thing. The word "vector" is meant to emphasize that quantum states form a vector space, the so-called Hilbert space.

Because they're synonyma, the question in the first paragraph is a meaningless talkative tautology, like "Is a car meant to denote just one vehicle or are many cars meant to be many different vehicles or the same vehicles?". What to do with such questions? There can't be any point in asking them or answering them if a car and a vehicle is really meant to be the same thing.

Each vector may be decomposed to components, given a basis. The vector is uniquely specified by the coordinates $(x,y,z,\dots)$ where the coordinates $x,y,z,\dots$ are complex in the case of the Hilbert space. Sometimes, the coordinate $x$ is called the "component" in which case it isn't a state at all, and one can't compare it with states in any way. In other contexts, and more accurately, the word "component" means $x\cdot \vec e_x$, including the basis vector in the corresponding direction, in which case the "component" is another quantum state i.e. another state vector, mathematically different from the original one whenever $y\neq 0$ or $z\neq 0$ or when other coordinates are nonzero.

When a physical system is in the state given by coordinates $(x,y,z)$, complex amplitudes, then it has the probability $|x|^2$ to be found in the state of the first component (in the second sense), $|y|^2$ in the second component, and so on.

The state vectors evolve according to a well-known equation. Whether it's easy or hard is up to a taste. Physics doesn't produce such value (or moral) statements. But we may still say that it is incorrect to say that the evolution between "quantum states" is easy while the evolution between "state vectors" is hard. Because they are the same thing, the process is equally easy or equally hard whatever is the definition of the "ease".

Comment: Your answer is surely clarifying for the OP but (just for completeness) Hilbert space vectors are not the best way to describe a quantum state because they are not uniquely defined (you can freely choose the phase factor). This freedom is sometimes important in applications. Usually a state is thought of either as a ray of the Hilbert space (i.e. equivalence class, up to the phase factor, of normalized vectors) or as a density matrix (i.e. an orthogonal projection or convex sum of projections on the Hilbert space), that allows the description of states that are a statistical mixture.